# C htons or inet_addr array

Tags: c

I am new to programming.

I am reading from a file using fgets and have placed the file contents into an array.

The file content is like these addresses seperated by a newline `\n`:

```
192.168.1.0
192.168.1.1
192.168.1.5
192.168.1.7
```

I am trying to use the array in the network function inet_addr and htons to connect.

How can I use the array into the function like this?

One by one? How would I do that?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: What have you already tried so far? Please show your actual code. Yes, you would have to process one address at a time. `inet_addr()` only accepts one address at a time, as does `connect()`. What are you trying to accomplish with the addresses?

Comment: suggest using `strtok()` in a loop, 1) checking the returned value of each call to strtok() to assure an new sub string was found.  2) if sub string found, pass that sub string to inet_addr() .  after reading each line, a call to strtok() would look something like: `char * address; if ( address = strtok(inputbuffer, " " ) ) {inet_addr( address );` for the first call and ` if ( address = strtok( NULL, " " ) ) {inet_addr( address );`  for the following calls

Comment: As I read your question, the addresses are not separated by a newline,  rather, they are separated by 'white space'  (space, newline, tab, etc)

Comment: @user3629249 that was due to bad formatting in the question.

Answer (score 0):

inet_addr is obsolete because it can't determine valid input of 255.255.255.255 from an error condition in its return code. Use inet_aton intead.

```
char buffer[81];
struct in_addr ip;
while(fgets(buffer, 80, f)) {
    buffer[strlen(buffer) - 1] = 0;
    if (1 == inet_aton(buffer, &ip)) {
        /* good line */
    } else {
        /* bad line */
    }
}
```

Comment: `fgets()` null terminates its output, you don't need to do it manually. If the output were not already null terminated, your use of `strlen()` would not work. Also, the question asked for help with `inet_addr()`, not `inet_aton()`.

Comment: fgets leaves the trailing newline on -- that line cuts it off.